# Checking CA in socket.io-client

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, websocket, socket.io

I have created an HTTPS server with socket.io and a client with socket.io-client.
Problem is that apparently socket.io-client does not check validity of HTTPS connection by the given CA in it's option.
For clarification here's a sample code: In simple https request if I do not provide CA in client I get `Error: unable to verify the first certificate`, but with socket.io-client connection establishes, which is totally not what I want.

```
//Client

var https = require('https'),
    socketClient = require('socket.io-client'),
    fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    // IT'S EXPECTED THAT I DON'T PROVIED CA, HTTPS CONNECTION FAILS
    //ca: fs.readFileSync('cert/ca.crt'),
    agent: false
};

var socket = socketClient('https://localhost', options);

socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Connected to hub');
    socket.emit('msg', function(resp){
        console.log('Response: ' + resp);
    });
});
```

And server :

```
// Server

var https = require('https'),
    socketIo = require('socket.io'),
    fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    // CERTIFICATE HAS BEEN SIGNED WITH CA
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert/signed.crt'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('cert/signed.key'),
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var app = https.createServer(options, function(req, res) {
    res.end('Hi');
});

var io = socketIo(app);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('Connected !');

    socket.on('msg', function(cb) {
        console.log('Msg recved');
        cb('Client got it');
    });
});

app.listen(443, function() {
    console.log('Server Started ...');
});
```